# ANTLR matching wrong tokens

Tags: antlr4

mytest.g4

```
lexer grammar mytest;

fragment HEX: '0' [xX] [0-9a-fA-F]+;
fragment INT: [0-9]+;
fragment WS: [\t ]+;
fragment NL: WS? ('\r'* '\n')+;

INFO: 'InfoFromDb' -> mode(INFO_MODE);
ID: 'ID from database' -> mode(ID_MODE);

mode INFO_MODE;
INFO_INTERMEDIATE: ':' WS*;// -> channel(HIDDEN);
//INFO_DATA: ~[\r\n]+; //(~('\r' | '\n'))+;
INFO_DATA: HEX ',' WS* [A-Za-z]+ WS* INT; //line 24:13 token recognition error at: '0xF8, F'
INFO_END: NL -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE);

mode ID_MODE;
ID_INTERMEDIATE: ':' WS* -> channel(HIDDEN);
ID_DATA: ~[\r\n]+;
// let's throw away the next token, but also use it to exit this mode
ID_END: NL -> skip, pushMode(DEFAULT_MODE);
```

pars.g4

```
parser grammar pars;
options {
  tokenVocab=mytest;
}

the_id: ID ID_DATA;
info: INFO INFO_INTERMEDIATE INFO_DATA INFO_END;
```

input

```
InfoFromDb: 0xF8, FooData 3
ID from database: 0x3, Blah ID: 0, Meta ID: 0, MetaB: 1
```

when I test the parser rule `the_id` with the input... it yields a parse tree of:

- InfoFromDb
- 0xF8, FooData 3
- \n
- ID from database

which just makes no sense...

similarly hard to understand, the `info` parser rule yields:

- InfoFromDb
- `<missing INFO_INTERMEDIATE>`
- : 0xF8, FooData 3
- \n

what's going on here? Are lexer rules somehow optional and being ignored? Am I misusing the `mode` stuff?

Comment: the second line is `ID from database: 0x3, Blah ID: 0, Meta ID: 0, MetaB: 1`... it starts with `ID`

Comment: and certainly `InfoFromDb` != `ID from database` so why would that match?

Comment: @BartKiers sorry, it still doesn't make sense

Comment: @BartKiers your answer and my comments on it got deleted... I didn't delete it